# How to properly replicate a web site's GET request to an API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to scrape data from this [page](https://www.jewelosco.com/shop/search-results.html?q=rice), specifically all the information about the products.

Using my browser's Inspect tool, I found that all of the products' data come from a JSON file; it is a response to a GET request sent to an API at this [URL](https://www.jewelosco.com/abs/pub/xapi/pgmsearch/v1/search/products?request-id=1771677643767994529&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jewelosco.com&pageurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jewelosco.com&pagename=search&rows=30&start=0&search-type=keyword&storeid=1118&featured=true&search-uid=&q=rice&sort=&featuredsessionid=&screenwidth=1533&dvid=web-4.1search&channel=instore&banner=jewelosco). Looking at the request headers I found the Subscription Key (i.e. `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`) and its value (i.e. `5e790236c84e46338f4290aa1050cdd4`).

I tried to get this JSON file by sending the GET request myself using the python request module, but it responded with a JSON file that contained an error message--`"appMsg": "Search encountered a problem. Please try again OSSR0033-R"`.

So it seems like I am able to connect to the API but the program on the other side is failing to find the product-data JSON file. I'm assuming the failure is due to a mistake in my GET request. **If this assumption is even valid, how can I properly replicate the request so that I can receive the expected output?**

##### Here is My Code:

```
import requests
import json

# query url 
def request_from_api(url, url_params, req_headers):
    response = requests.get(url, params=url_params, headers=req_headers)
    return response

def format_cookies(cookie_pairs):
     '''
     Takes a "list" of name-value pairs e.g. "cook1=value1; cook2=val2"
     '''
     pairs = [pair.split('=') for pair in cookie_pairs.split('; ')]
     formatted_pairs = {cookie_val[0]:cookie_val[1] for cookie_val in pairs}
     return formatted_pairs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # url that API is located at
    api_url = "https://www.jewelosco.com/abs/pub/xapi/pgmsearch/v1/search/products?"

    # url parameters for api_url
    url_params = {
            "request-id": "1771677643767994529",
            "url": "https://www.jewelosco.com",
            "pageurl": "https://www.jewelosco.com",
            "pagename": "search",
            "rows": "30",
            "start": "0",
            "search-type": "keyword",
            "storeid": "1118",
            "featured": "true",
            "search-uid": "",
            "q": "rice",
            "sort": "",
            "featuredsessionid": "",
            "screenwidth": "1533",
            "dvid": "web-4.1search",
            "channel": "instore",
            "banner": "jewelosco"
    }


    # API sub key
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "www.jewelosco.com",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "5e790236c84e46338f4290aa1050cdd4",
        "Referer": "https://www.jewelosco.com/shop/search-results.html?q=rice",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "TE": "trailers",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"
    }
    # List of cookie-value pairs copied from my browser's Inspect tool
    raw_form_cookies = "visid_incap_1990338=s+w9h0GrTSqb/iWdgj5yGT7p/2MAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD+pkwygiCfx/ikABjRUg/L; nlbi_1990338=mHC1ApVnlTLFJURPzoaznQAAAACG3swCSzQedoLPtuqqPhlT; incap_ses_8080_1990338=FeLoM/tDE2aUu2sos+0hcD7p/2MAAAAAyClJy0AvAh6rRWqmCVVCcw==; ECommBanner=jewelosco; abs_gsession=%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22COMMON%22%3A%7B%22Selection%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%2C%22userType%22%3A%22G%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22banner%22%3A%22jewelosco%22%7D%2C%22J4U%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%2C%22SHOP%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%7D%7D; SWY_SHARED_SESSION_INFO=%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22COMMON%22%3A%7B%22userType%22%3A%22G%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22banner%22%3A%22jewelosco%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%2C%22Selection%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22userData%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22J4U%22%3A%7B%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22userData%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22SHOP%22%3A%7B%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22userData%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D; abs_previouslogin=%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22COMMON%22%3A%7B%22Selection%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%2C%22userType%22%3A%22G%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22banner%22%3A%22jewelosco%22%7D%2C%22J4U%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%2C%22SHOP%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%7D%7D; SWY_SYND_USER_INFO=%7B%22storeAddress%22%3A%22%22%2C%22storeZip%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%7D; ECommSignInCount=0; SAFEWAY_MODAL_LINK=; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Wed+Mar+01+2023+18%3A10%3A25+GMT-0600+(Central+Standard+Time)&version=202212.1.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=2481ceef-8878-4f3b-924b-3b28079d9b13&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A0%2CC0004%3A0%2CC0003%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; nlbi_1990338_2147483392=jYckLK1heGBAHrRyzoaznQAAAACZvsW6rrz3C1oXWBs6UFc8; reese84=3:Gl8qjGMtFKfV15EgMleAnA==: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:XtGGSfw6IB+W6dYIh0iO+xPVdddBfiRA1zwKMhu0OmE=; mbox=session#2686aefa9dea422db9f92c9b39a01830#1677717696; at_check=true; ADRUM_BT=R:57|i:5124367|g:a106a4d3-bbb8-4619-8262-9d3f98852991652436|e:104|n:safeway-loyalty_d99a98d0-07cc-4871-98b7-0beac77d0580"
        
    formatted_cookies = format_cookies(raw_form_cookies)

    # combine api_url and url_params and make GET request with headers
    product_data = request_from_api(api_url, url_params, headers, formatted_cookies).json()

    # pretty print json file
    print(json.dumps(product_data, indent=3))
```

##### Actual Output:

```
{
   "appMsg": "[PS: Success.]",
   "primaryProducts": {
      "appCode": "400",
      "appMsg": "Search encountered a problem. Please try again OSSR0033-R",
      "pgmName": "search-products",
      "order": "1"
   },
   "appCode": "[PS: 200]"
}
```

##### Expected Output:

Its a large json file that contains all of the products information (e.g. name, price, quantity...). Here is "snippet" of it:

```
{
   "appMsg":"[PS: Success.]",
   "primaryProducts":{
      "response":{
         "numFound":725,
         "start":0,
         "isExactMatch":true,
         "docs":[
            {
               "name":"Signature SELECT Rice Enriched Long Grain - 5 Lb",
               "pid":"126150030",
               "upc":"0002113050205",
               "id":"126150030",
               "featured":false,
               "inventoryAvailable":"1",
               "pastPurchased":false,
               "restrictedValue":"0",
               "salesRank":99999,
               "price":4.99,
               "basePrice":4.99,
               "pricePer":1.0,
               "displayType":"-1",
               "aisleId":"1_6_9_9",
               "aisleName":"Rice|1_6_9",
               "departmentName":"Grains, Pasta & Sides",
               "shelfName":"White Rice",
               "unitOfMeasure":"LB",
               "sellByWeight":"I",
               "averageWeight":[
                  "0.00"
               ],
               "unitQuantity":"LB",
               "displayUnitQuantityText":"ea",
               "previousPurchaseQty":0,
               "maxPurchaseQty":0,
               "prop65WarningIconRequired":false,
               "isArProduct":true,
               "isMtoProduct":false,
               "customizable":false,
               "inStoreShoppingElig":false,
               "preparationTime":"0",
               "isMarketplaceItem":"N",
               "triggerQuantity":0,
               "channelEligibility":{
                  "pickUp":true,
                  "delivery":true,
                  "inStore":true,
                  "shipping":false
               },
               "channelInventory":{
                  "delivery":"1",
                  "pickup":"1",
                  "instore":"1",
                  "shipping":"0"
               },
               "productReview":{
                  "avgRating":"4.8",
                  "reviewCount":"64",
                  "isReviewWriteEligible":"true",
                  "isReviewDisplayEligible":"true",
                  "isForOnetimeReview":"true",
                  "reviewTemplateType":"default"
              }
      }
   },
   "appCode":"[PS: 200]"
}
```

## Update:

Despite adding all of the request headers, the response is the same.

Here are all of the headers I added:

```
headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "www.jewelosco.com",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "5e790236c84e46338f4290aa1050cdd4",
        "Referer": "https://www.jewelosco.com/shop/search-results.html?q=rice",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "TE": "trailers",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"
    }
all_cookies = {
        "visid_incap_1990338":"s+w9h0GrTSqb/iWdgj5yGT7p/2MAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD+pkwygiCfx/ikABjRUg/L", 
        "nlbi_1990338": "mHC1ApVnlTLFJURPzoaznQAAAACG3swCSzQedoLPtuqqPhlT",
        "incap_ses_8080_1990338":"FeLoM/tDE2aUu2sos+0hcD7p/2MAAAAAyClJy0AvAh6rRWqmCVVCcw", 
        "ECommBanner": "jewelosco", 

        "abs_gsession":"%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22COMMON%22%3A%7B%22Selection%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%2C%22userType%22%3A%22G%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22banner%22%3A%22jewelosco%22%7D%2C%22J4U%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%2C%22SHOP%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%7D%7D",

        "SWY_SHARED_SESSION_INFO":"%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22COMMON%22%3A%7B%22userType%22%3A%22G%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22banner%22%3A%22jewelosco%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%2C%22Selection%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22userData%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22J4U%22%3A%7B%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22userData%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22SHOP%22%3A%7B%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22userData%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D",

        "abs_previouslogin":"%7B%22info%22%3A%7B%22COMMON%22%3A%7B%22Selection%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%2C%22userType%22%3A%22G%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22banner%22%3A%22jewelosco%22%7D%2C%22J4U%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%2C%22SHOP%22%3A%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%7D%7D%7D",

        "SWY_SYND_USER_INFO":"%7B%22storeAddress%22%3A%22%22%2C%22storeZip%22%3A%2252732%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%221118%22%2C%22preference%22%3A%22J4U%22%7D",
        "ECommSignInCount": "0", 
        "SAFEWAY_MODAL_LINK": "", 
        "OptanonConsent": "isGpcEnabled",
        "nlbi_1990338_2147483392":"jYckLK1heGBAHrRyzoaznQAAAACZvsW6rrz3C1oXWBs6UFc8",
        "reese84": "3:Gl8qjGMtFKfV15EgMleAnA",
        "mbox": "session#2686aefa9dea422db9f92c9b39a01830#1677717696",
        "at_check": "true",
        "ADRUM_BT": "R:57|i:5124367|g:a106a4d3-bbb8-4619-8262-9d3f98852991652436|e:104|n:safeway-loyalty_d99a98d0-07cc-4871-98b7-0beac77d0580"
     }
```

Here is a function I made that formats a list of cookie-value pairs (e.g `Cookie: "c1=v1; c2=v2; c3=v3"`) into a dictionary where the keys are cookie names and the values are the cookie values--this format is needed to work with `request.get()` :

```
def format_cookies(cookie_pairs):
     '''
     Takes a "list" of name-value pairs e.g. "cook1=value1; cook2=val2"
     '''
     pairs = [pair.split('=') for pair in cookie_pairs.split('; ')]
     formatted_pairs = {cookie_val[0]:cookie_val[1] for cookie_val in pairs}
     return formatted_pairs
```

I have altered the original script to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 1):

For this website specifically you just need a fresh request-id in the get request url_params. I've found the cookies don't matter at all.

The request-id is composed of 19 numbers. First 3 are random, middle 6 are a server time code that changes periodically. Remaining are random. This was my function to generate fresh request id. Time code appears to be generated from another stable request where cookies don't matter.

```
def get_request_id():
    data = {
        "checksum": "1640249083",
        "_rand": "lrvnwar",
        "rid": "r310947",
        "d": '{"INQ":{"siteID":10006484,"custID":"-6153494727971827858","scheduleTZs":{}}}',
    }

    response = requests.post("https://albertsons.inq.com/tagserver/init/initFramework", data=data)

    r = response.json()["INQ"]["serverTime"][0:7]

    first_chunk = random.randint(100, 999)
    second_chunk = r
    third_chunk = random.randint(100000000, 999999999)

    request_id = int(str(first_chunk) + str(second_chunk) + str(third_chunk))

    return request_id
```

If you figure out how to scrape storeid from zip code let me know as that is where I am currently stuck :)